# MySQL lowest and latest price per product

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
    price_history (Primary: id)
    +----+------------+------+---------+-------+------------+
    | id | id_product | sku  | id_shop | price |  date_add  |
    +----+------------+------+---------+-------+------------+

    | 1  | 11         | 101  | 1001    | 10    | 2017-07-01 |
    | 2  | 12         | 101  | 1002    | 15    | 2017-07-01 |
    | 3  | 13         | 101  | 1003    | 20    | 2017-07-01 |
    | 4  | 11         | 101  | 1001    | 11    | 2017-07-02 | <-- lowest latest

    | 5  | 14         | 102  | 1001    | 45    | 2017-07-01 |
    | 6  | 15         | 102  | 1002    | 45    | 2017-07-01 |
    | 7  | 16         | 102  | 1003    | 45    | 2017-07-01 | <-- shop 1003 is the lowest,
    latest among shops and should not be display, because the shop monitored is 1001
    | 8  | 15         | 102  | 1002    | 60    | 2017-07-02 | 
    | 9  | 14         | 102  | 1001    | 55    | 2017-07-02 | 

    |10  | 17         | 103  | 1001    | 90    | 2017-07-01 |
    |11  | 18         | 103  | 1002    | 90    | 2017-07-01 |
    |12  | 19         | 103  | 1003    | 90    | 2017-07-01 |
    |13  | 17         | 103  | 1001    | 100   | 2017-07-02 | <-- lowest latest 
    |14  | 18         | 103  | 1002    | 100   | 2017-07-02 |
    |15  | 19         | 103  | 1003    | 100   | 2017-07-02 |
    +----+------------+------+---------+-------+------------+

    product (primary: id_product)
    +------------+---- ---+-----+--------------+---------+
    | id_product | active | sku | product_name | id_shop |
    +------------+--------+-----+--------------+---------+
    | 11         | 1      | 101 | Red          | 1001    |
    | 12         | 1      | 101 | A bit red    | 1002    |
    | 13         | 1      | 101 | Very red0    | 1003    |
    | 14         | 1      | 102 | Blue         | 1001    |
    | 15         | 1      | 102 | A bit blue   | 1002    |
    | 16         | 1      | 102 | Very blue    | 1003    |
    | 17         | 1      | 103 | Green        | 1001    |
    | 18         | 1      | 103 | A bit green  | 1002    |
    | 19         | 1      | 103 | Very green   | 1003    |
    | 20         | 0      | 104 | Discontinued | 1001    |
    | 21         | 0      | 104 | Out of stock | 1002    |
    | 22         | 0      | 104 | Varnish      | 1003    |
    +------------+--------+-----+--------------+---------+

    shop (primary: id_shop)
    +---------+--------+
    | id_shop | name   |
    +---------+--------+
    | 1001    | Shop A |
    | 1002    | Shop B |
    | 1003    | SHop C |
    +---------+--------+
```

Every shop has a different product name, but has international number (sku).

ID shop to monitor: 1001 (Shop A)

Already search in stackoverflow, but i cannot get the right one.
How can i get the lowest and latest price per sku.
Im still newbie that not understand subselect

This what i have done so far

```
    SELECT pph.id, s.name, h2.price, h2.sku
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(h.id) max_id, MIN(h.price) min_price, h.id, h.id_shop
        FROM price h
        GROUP BY sku
    ) pph 
    LEFT JOIN price h2 ON (h2.id = max_id)
    LEFT JOIN shop s ON (s.id_shop = pph.id_shop)
```

Then in the last i need only show the monitored shop, 'Shop A'

Expected result:

```
    +----+------------+------+---------+-------+
    | id | id_product | sku  | id_shop | price | 
    +----+------------+------+---------+-------+
    | 4  | 11         | 101  | 1001    | 11    |
    |13  | 17         | 103  | 1001    | 100   |
    +----+------------+------+---------+-------+
```

Lowest price for sku 102 is shop 1003, so we dont need to show them.

JSFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba3a2

Thank you

**Need help, still not found the solution**

Comment: show your expected result too

Comment: @JYoThI expected result added

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh yes you are right.  `date_add` added

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh the second sign 102 `<-- lowest latest` corrected. Your eyes sharp like an eagle...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using a correlated subquery with limit clause:

```
select *
from price_history h
where id_shop = 1001
and id = (select id
          from price_history p
          where h.sku = p.sku
          and h.id_shop = p.id_shop
          order by date_add desc, price asc
          limit 1
          );
```

The above is simple solution but may suffer from performance issues for larger dataset.

You can use the below join based solution then:

```
select *
from price_history
join (
    select sku, date_add, min(price) as price
    from price_history
    join (
        select sku, max(date_add) as date_add
        from price_history
        where id_shop = 1001
        group by sku
    ) t using (sku, date_add)
    where id_shop = 1001
    group by sku, date_add
) t using (sku, date_add, price)
where id_shop = 1001
```

or

```
select *
from price_history
join (
    select sku, date_add, id_shop, min(price) as price
    from price_history
    join (
        select sku, id_shop, max(date_add) as date_add
        from price_history
        where id_shop = 1001
        group by sku, id_shop
    ) t using (sku, date_add, id_shop)
    group by sku, date_add, id_shop
) t using (sku, date_add, price, id_shop);
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/TVW75280)

Comment: This might be simplest. I suspect that nested uncorrelated subqueries will be faster.

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes.. I've added join and sub query based solutions.

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh corrected second price_history sku 102 `<-- shop 1003 is the lowest,
    latest among shops and should not be display, because the shop monitored is 1001`

Comment: @inMILD How is that row the lowest latest? Shouldn't the row for latest date and *then* lowest price should be chosen? I think I still do not fully understand your logic.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Since shop 1003 did not add new price for sku 102, he is the lowest price among other shop, and his price the latest on his own.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you max `date_add` per  sku for a shop

```
SELECT sku, MAX(date_add)
FROM price_history
WHERE id_shop = 1001
GROUP BY sku;
```

You can then wrap this into another query and `JOIN` with `price_history` again, to get the result, e.g.:

```
SELECT ph.id, ph.id_product, ph.sku, ph.id_shop, ph.price
FROM proce_history ph JOIN (
 SELECT sku, MAX(date_add) AS `date_add`
 FROM price_history
 WHERE id_shop = 1001
 GROUP BY sku
) a ON ph.sku = a.sku AND ph.date_add = a.date_add;
```

Comment: @inMILD So, in your example, `11` is latest but not lowest?

Comment: which 11? id_product or id?

Comment: @inMILD you need timestamp column in your tables. It will resolve the problem . I have one question for you , on what basis you say it's lowest and this value is latest. So you need timestamp column

Comment: Then u min of timestamp and Max of timestamp per sku

Comment: @karan arora `date_add` added

Comment: @inMILD so it's latest and not lowest?

Comment: @karan arora lowest among shops

Comment: This is half the answer